# How to continually process last lines of two files when the files change randomly?

Tags: bash

I have the following simple snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -f "data/top.right.log" | while read val1
do
  val2=$(tail -n 1 "data/top.left.log")    
  echo $(echo "$val1 - $val2" | bc)
done
```

`top.left.log` and `top.right.log` are files to which some other processes continually write. The bash script simply subtracts the last lines of both files and show a result.

I would like to make the script more efficient. In pseudo-code I would like to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

magiccommand "data/top.right.log" "data/top.left.log" | while read val1 val2
do
  echo $(echo "$val1 - $val2" | bc)
done
```

so that whenever `top.left.log` **OR** `top.right.log` changes the echo command is called.

I have already tried various snippets from StackOverflow but often they rely on the fact that the files do not change or that both files contain the same amount of lines which is not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `inotify-tools` you can use following command:

```
inotifywait -q -e modify file1 file2
```

Description:

```
   inotifywait  efficiently waits for changes to files using Linux's inotify(7) interface.
   It is suitable for waiting for changes to files from shell scripts.
   It can either exit once an event occurs, or continually execute and output events as they occur.
```

An example:

```
while : ;
do
    inotifywait -q -e modify file1 file2
    echo `tail -n1 file1`
    echo `tail -n1 file2`
done
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to read the whole content of both files every time one of them change change?

Comment: @MartinVseticka I've modified the example for you.

Comment: Using `tail -n1` each time through the loop is both inefficient (you read the entire file each time to get the last line) and lossy (you only see the *last* line written to each file, not *every* line written since the last call to `inotifywait`).

Comment: @chepner tail doesn't read the entire file. It seeks t the end of the file and look backwards.

Comment: So then it's just lossy.

Comment: It might be. But the OP version is also lossy. Anyhow, without the clear specification it's hard to give the 'correct' solution e.g. we don't know how often the files can be changed or if they have only 1 or more new lines etc.

Comment: @chepner: It does not mind that it is lossy for me. I was kind of afraid that `tail -n1` is inefficient but Dawid's solution seems to be better than mine.

Comment: @DawidGrabowski: I'll try your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary file that you touch each time the files are processed. If any of the files is newer than the temporary file, process the files again.

```
#!/bin/bash
log1=top.left.log
log2=top.right.log
tmp=last_change

last_change=0
touch "$tmp"

while : ; do
    if [[ $log1 -nt $tmp || $log2 -nt $tmp ]] ; then
        touch "$tmp"
        x=$(tail -n1 "$log1")
        y=$(tail -n1 "$log2")
        echo $(( x - y ))
    fi
done
```

You might need to remove the temporary file once the script is killed.

If the files are changing fast, you might miss some lines. Otherwise, adding `sleep 1` somewhere would decrease the CPU usage.

Comment: Your script uses much more resources than mine. If the input files are getting larger and larger, your script does require more and more disk operations. I expect that `tail` reads whole file but I'm not sure how it is implemented. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MartinVseticka: I'd probably reach for Perl and its [File::Tail](http://p3rl.org/File::Tail).

Comment: That's super inefficient! inotify is the way to go for monitoring file changes on Linux. Other system have their own frameworks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `tail` every time, you can open file descriptors once and read line after line. This makes use of the fact that the files are kept open, and `read` will always read from the next line of a file.

First, open the files in bash, assigning them file descriptors `3` and `4`

```
exec 3<file1 4<file2
```

Now, you can read from these files using `read -u <fd>`. In combination with `inotifywait` of [Dawid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39201138/1314743), this gives you an efficient way to read files line by line:

```
while :; do
    # TODO: add some break condition

    # wait until one of the files has changed
    inotifywait -q -e modify file1 file2

    # read the next line of file1 into val1_new
    # if file1 has not changed and there is no new line, read will return with failure
    read -u 3 val1_new && val1="$val1_new"

    # same for file2
    read -u 4 val2_new && val2="$val2_new"
done
```

You may extend this by reading until you have reached the last line, or parsing `inotifywait`'s output to detect which file has changed.

Comment: I think that last line is important; otherwise, you may be forced to wait for a new update to a file before you can read data written during a previous update.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to parse the output of `tail -f` and display the difference in value whenever the `==> <==` pattern is found.

I came up with this script:

```
$ cat test.awk
$0 ~ /==>.*right.*<==/ {var=1} 
$0 ~ /==>.*left.*<==/ {var=2} 

$1~/[0-9]+/ && var==1 { val1=$1 }
$1~/[0-9]+/ && var==2 { val2=$1 }

val1 != "" && val2 != "" && $1~/[0-9]+/{
    print val1-val2
}
```

The script assume the values are integer `[0-9]+` in both file.

You can use it like this:

```
tail -f top.right.log top.left.log | awk -f test.awk
```

Whenever a value is appended in any of the file, the difference between the last value of each file is displayed.